# variation in system call open overheads

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark open system call with my code that read timestamp counter

```
    overhead = measure_tsc_overhead();
    int i;
        unsigned long t0;

        synch_tsc();
        t0 = rdtscll();
        input_fd = open ("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (input_fd == -1) {
                perror ("open");
                return 2;
        }
     printf("open syscall overhead is %ld\n",(rdtscllp() - t0 - overhead));
```

functions used have following definitions

```
static inline void synch_tsc(void)
{
    asm volatile("cpuid" : : : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
}

static inline unsigned long rdtscll(void)
{
    unsigned int a, d;
    asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "%rbx", "%rcx");
    return ((unsigned long) a) | (((unsigned long) d) << 32);
}

static inline unsigned long rdtscllp(void)
{
    unsigned int a, d;
    asm volatile("rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "%rbx", "%rcx");
    return ((unsigned long) a) | (((unsigned long) d) << 32);
}

static unsigned long measure_tsc_overhead(void)
{
    unsigned long t0, t1, overhead = ~0UL;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        t0 = rdtscll();
        asm volatile("");
        t1 = rdtscllp();
        if (t1 - t0 < overhead)
            overhead = t1 - t0;
    }

    return overhead;
}
```

I am getting following overheads for different runs

```
open syscall overhead is 24497
open syscall overhead is 13523
open syscall overhead is 9025
open syscall overhead is 5784
open syscall overhead is 26390
```

My concern is the huge variation in overheads.

what is the reason for such variation?

If this variation is normal (may be due to some cache) what value represents my actual result?

Comment: Well, what kind of storage is it?  Spinner or SSD? Flash or fileserver?  If it's a spinner or the like, mechanical bits may have to move sometimes.

Comment: i am using laptop with spinner storage. one anothe run cross 100,000 mark :). getpid variation is with in 50 cycles so ....

Comment: OK, there you go...  laptop spinning drives are always low performance anyway - they sacrifice speed for low power consumption and durability.

Comment: is any way present to stabilize the output ? laptop is continuously on power not on battery

Comment: I suspect not.  If the head has to move, then it's going to take a long time.

Comment: There are some quirks in your asm.  I'm not sure `rdtscp` and `rdtsc` need to clobber bx and cx.  And doesn't cpuid use eax as an input to determine what info to return?  Since you aren't explicitly setting a value, each call could (in theory) be doing different work.  But more importantly, keep in mind that the disk is shared with other apps (including system stuff).  Your 'open' request can get blocked behind other work.

Comment: ah! any idea how does LMbench calculate system call read latency? latencies generated by LMbench are consist.